# Problems setting up speed on PTZ absolute and relative modes

Tags: c#, onvif

I'm working with a ONVIF compliant network camera. So far I've been able to move the camera using the Continous move operation.The problem is that I can't set the speed parameter in the Absolute and Relative move operations. I've read the ONVIF's PTZ specs,but nothing works.
No matters what value I set, it always executes the default speed value.
The speed parameter is set throw the following code:

`_selectedDevice.PtzClient().AbsoluteMove(_selectedProfile,
                new PTZVector
                {...,
                new PTZSpeed//());
                {
                    PanTilt = new Vector2D
                    {
                        x = (float)_nuAbsoluteSpeed.Value,
                        y = (float)_nuAbsoluteSpeed.Value,
                    },
                    Zoom = new Vector1D
                    {
                        x = (float)_nuAbsoluteSpeed.Value,

                    }
                });`
I also tried to set the space parameter parameter but the result is the same.
Any help?

Comment: Did you manage with this? Or just left it as is?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the reason is that any absolute or relative move is supposed to take you directly to the position as quickly as possible.  Speed is used when you tell the camera to go in a particular direction indefinitely like when using a joystick.  Note: relative positioning is really still absolute positioning, it is just relative to current position rather than zero.

Comment: According to the specs the speed parameter is used for every move regardless the distance to cover.

Comment: Have you tried using other ONVIF software to move the camera at a different speed?  According to the spec, "speed spaces" may not be available even if "velocity spaces" are.  Have you checked the spec for your specific camera?

Comment: yes i did, the camera have default values for space and speed, besides the zoom (for example) it moves but ignores the speed value I provide.